# Set grid columns always be 100%

Tags: html, css

I created a simple CSS grid container with three columns when I add data to column one it creates space between columns one and two for some reason, I want my columns always to be width 100% of the available space for it.

Note: I do not want to set the static size of each column like: `grid-template-columns: 200,200,200` I want them always 100%

How can I solve this?

Code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.column {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" *ngIf="selectedMenuItem === menu[3]">
  <div class="column col-3 offset-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test Test Test Test, Test/Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test Test; Test/Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Column 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Column 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As comments below I try:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.column {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div class="container" *ngIf="selectedMenuItem === menu[3]">
      <div class="column col-3 offset-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <label>This is a test of column 100%</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <label>Test Test Test Test Test, Test/Test</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <label>Test Test Test; Test/Test</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Column 2 </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Column 3 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the text is not at 100%, how can I solve this?

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing CSS grids with bootstrap grids, you are using `col-3 offset-md-2` which adds a lot of extra style (and sets a 25% width for the first column). You shouldn't mix those things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.column {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" *ngIf="selectedMenuItem === menu[3]">
  <div class="column col offset-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test Test Test Test, Test/Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <label>Test Test Test; Test/Test</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Column 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>Column 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I still don't understand the result you want.
But maybe like this?
You just define col-3 and I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You can use fractional units which will make them fill up all the available space.
You can play around with sizing of each column such as `1fr 2fr 1fr` to make the centre column twice the size of the outside columns.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
<div class="column col-3 offset-md-2">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Test Test</label>
        <label>Test Test Test Test Test, Test/Test</label>
        <label>Test Test Test; Test/Test</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem, because the label break line and I want break only when reaching 100% of the 100% of column size

Comment: The labels are on different lines because you have them in `div.row` which makes them their own rows. If you want all the `label`s in the same row then have them all in the same parent `div`

Comment: See update on answer

Comment: I tried and it's the same result, I update my question with the replica of your answer at row one, and the `label` still breaking

Comment: Try changing the html to my updated answer too